# Shopify / Liquid - adding new contact form textarea/variable to be captured

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify, liquid

I want to add another textarea to my Shopify contact form that will be sent to me when a customer emails me. The current textarea is as below:

```html
<label for="{{ formId }}-message">Please provide further detail</label>
<textarea
  class="textarea-vertical-resize-only"
  rows="10"
  id="{{ formId }}-message"
  name="contact[{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}]"
  required="required"
>
{% if form.body %}{{ form.body }}{% endif %}</textarea
>
```

The issue is that it uses the variable `{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}` - so I believe I need to create a new variable for another textarea input that it will capture.

What do I need to do to be able to have another unique textarea for it to capture and send to my email?

Comment: you can use onkeyup/onblur javacript method  to get input and process it through value copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, your issue is with `{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}`, this liquid code is a translation of an object you have in your locales -> en.default.json or any other translations.

What you are looking at is having something like this:

```
<label for="{{ formId }}-further-details">Please provide further detail</label>
<textarea
  class="textarea-vertical-resize-only"
  rows="10"
  id="{{ formId }}-further-details"
  name="contact[further-details]"
  required="required"
>
{% if form.further-details %}{{ form.further-details }}{% endif %}
</textarea>
```

Notice that the name of the text area is **contact[further-details]** and I use the same variable "further-details" and the content **{% if form.further-details %}{{ form.further-details }}{% endif %}**

Hope this helps to solve your issue.

Cheers